# Laravel function to convert a realpath() to an absolute URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have declared a path pointing to a folder like this:

```php
$path = realpath(public_path('uploads'));
```

This gives me that value: `/var/www/mywebsite/public/uploads`

Now, I want to turn this into an absolute URL, like this: `http://www.mywebsite.com/uploads`

Here is what I did:

```php
dd(asset($path));     // Wrong: http://www.mywebsite.com/var/www/mywebsite/public/uploads
dd(url($path);        // Same.
dd(asset('uploads')); // Right, but I only want to use $path
```

Is there a pre-built way to achieve this in Laravel 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours `$path` is taken relatively to `public` folder with `public_path('uploads')`, so, `'uploads'` by itself points to absolute path. Just add host part to it. Like:

```
$inPublic = 'uploads';
$localPath = realpath(public_path($inPublic));

// then, either
$url = url("/" . trim($inPublic, "/\\"));    

// or
$publicPath = realpath(public_path());
$relativePart = str_replace($publicPath, '', $localPath);
$url = url("/" . trim($relativePart, "/\\"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there with `asset($path)`.

Just amend this to `asset('uploads')` and this will resolve to  `http://www.mywebsite.com/uploads`.

The asset URL helper generates a URL to the public folder of your Laravel application. You then just add the folder you want to go to from there.